# Keep menu selection throw views

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I'm using mvc to go to an index that returns a partial view then render it in the body of a layout, then the different parts of the view (edit, add, delete)I use ajax and angular to render different parts of it. So I've got one index with different parts  (edit, delete, add) that render the corresponding components and update them throw ajax. The thing is that I only want to render the section in the layout corresponding to the partial view, I mean in the renderbody() where the partial is rendered. But I dont want the header of the layout  to to postback in order to mantain the options selected.

Here is an image:

[image]

This is the layout, the usual mvc layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p class="site-title">
                 @Html.ActionLink("su logotipo aquí", "Index", "Home")</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <select>
            <option>Option 1</option>
            <option>Option 2</option>
        </select>
    </header>
    <div id="body">
        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
           @RenderBody()
        </section>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Mi aplicación ASP.NET MVC</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

My View:

```
@{
 Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

 <h2>holaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</h2>
```

My controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
```

In short:
I need to know how to use partial views, to render it in the layout, mantaining the options selected and not doing post back to better look of the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find a good solution to your problem, consider implementing bootstrap tabs http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs
I've had a similar problem and without finding a solution I've switched from select box to tabs. 
Basically you play with tabs and ng-includes like this:

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="" data-toggle="tab">TabName1 
    <ng-include  src="'myFirstPartialTemplate.html'">
</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-toggle="tab">TabName2
<ng-include  src="'mySecondPartialTemplate.html'">
</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your view is a partial view, then it should not have the property 'Layout' set.

I would do the following:

Make your index page return a View:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Create a another action to return your partial:

```
public ActionResult MyPartial()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

In your index page, if you wish, render your partial in the body.

```
@{
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>holaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</h2>
@Html.Partial("MyPartial")
```

Not sure if this is what you need, but I hope it helps.